# Do jQuery functions return a value like Javascript? How?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In Javascript we can declare a variable and we can call a function. The function will return a value and will be assigned to the variable. Is this possible in jQuery?

I want to know if my previous function is finished or not. I want to get the result success or failure and call another function based on first function's result

I use a function `setTimeout` for `blockUI`.

How can I check if that timeout is due to another function?

Do `.val` or `$.get` work for the above purposes?

Comment: Please show your code as the question is quite incomprehensible.

Comment: jQuery *is* a JavaScript library, so it plays by the same rules.

Comment: Pardon, may be my English was weird.
am using blockui function for fading the screen and show a messsage . this will be for 3000ms. so after 3000ms i want to call another fucntion which will redirect to a new page.

So i want to know how can i call the second fucntion after 3000ms. 
Second question is ,like js var a =function dosome();
how to do in Jquery.
3rd is how can i redirect a page using jquery after 3000ms.
I hope the questions are clear this time. Am a newbie and even asking questions having difficulties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Based on your comments...

*First question:*

You should probably look at some of the [blockUI demos](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#demos).

It looks like `blockUI` has a callback `onBlock:` that calls a function after the `fadeIn` is done.

```
onBlock: function() { 
   alert('Page is now blocked; fadeIn complete'); 
}
```

*Second question:*

jQuery is just a library of javascript code, therefore you can assign functions to variables the same way you always do.

```
var a = function dosome() {
    // do something
};

a(); // call the function
```

*Third question:*

You mean you want to redirect after the 3000ms `fadeIn` of the `blockUI`? You would do it in the callback that I pointed out under question 1 above. But of course this will make the entire page change, including the `blockUI`.

```
window.location = "http://somedomain.com/some/path";
```

---

Some clarification in your question is needed.

It sounds like you have a function that sets a `setTimeout()` for some purpose, and that function is reused, so you need to reference the correct instance of `setTimeout()`.

If so, you can have your function return the `setTimeout()` instance, and use that reference to clear it if needed.

```
function unblockUI(dur) {
    return setTimeout(function() {
        $.unblockUI();
    }, dur);
}

var someTimeout = unblockUI(1000);
clear(someTimeout);

var someOtherTimeout = unblockUI(1000);
clear(someOtherTimeout);
```

Is this close to what you're asking?

Comment: hey..thnx anyway...  how  can i redirect to new page after 1000.?

Comment: thanks buddy. The callback worked
actually i copy the blockui from the same demo site only. 
but i didnt look int the call back examples .
 setTimeout(function() { 
            $.unblockUI({ 
                onUnblock: function(){ window.location="http://www.google.com/"; } 
            }); 
        }, 3000); 
     

work fine :)